# Binary Absolute value

Tags: binary

If I want to represent a number in binary with absolute value and its sign I do this:
F.e. 3 = 11 -> 011 (0 because it's positive)
-7 = 111 -> 1111 (I added a 1 because it's negative).

If I have this situation and I represent the numbers in binary with sign and absolute value

-3 = 11 -> 111
-7 = 111 -> 1111

and then I want to sum them

1111 +
   111 =
....

is this format correct? 
Because -3 is shorter than -7 in binary and if I add a zero in this way

1111 +
0111 =
....

will I lose the sign of -3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a dangerous way to add numbers and is a reason why it's trouble to have the first bit being the sign and everything after being the positive representation of the number.

I would solve this by doing:

```
 111
+ 11
=1010 = ten
```

Then add a 1 in front to represent it is negative, to get 11010.

A general strategy might be to do addition/subtraction without the sign bit, and then add it at the end based on if the result is negative or positive.

For example: what is 7-3?

7 = 0111
-3 = 111, 3 = 011

```
 111
- 11
=100 = four
```

Then know that 7-3 is positive, so add the sign bit at the end to get 0100

A solution to this problem is something called "2's Complement"